# ReactJS buttons change color on click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 3 buttons in reactjs created with [Material UI Buttons](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/).

```
<>
<Button variant="contained">Button 1</Button>
<Button variant="contained">Button 2</Button>
<Button variant="contained">Button3</Button>
</>
```

How can I make that when clicking on one, it changes it's color (let's say blue) and the other ones reset to Default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because React use JSX, you can put javascript in your html component. 
We can imagine a single state that manage your buttons.

in your component you create a state containing integer

```
const [buttonSelected, setButtonselected] = useState(0);
```

I'm using the react hook syntax, but it also depend on you implementation.

`buttonSelected` is the current value of the state and `setButtonselected` is the function that change the state. When you call it, React will rerender your component and change the display .

You can now add a click function on your return

```
...
<Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setButtonSelected(1)}>Button 1</Button>
<Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setButtonSelected(2)} >Button 2</Button>
<Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setButtonSelected(3)}>Button3 </Button>
...
```

This will change the value of buttonSelected each time you click a button.

We now need to change the color , for that we will use use makeStyle, but there is other way to do so.

First, create a style element outside of your component.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
            selected: {
                background: 'blue',
            },
            default:{
                background: 'default',
            }
        }
    ),
);
```

Then call it in your component

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

And finally you can set the style that you want depending on the value

```
...
<Button className={(buttonSelected === 1) ? classes.selected : classes.default} variant.....
<Button className={(buttonSelected === 2) ? classes.selected : classes.default} variant.....
<Button className={(buttonSelected === 3) ? classes.selected : classes.default} variant.....
...
```

This is a ternary operator, it's the equivalent of

```
if(buttonSelected === 1){
    return classes.selected
} else {
    return classes.default
}
```

And it should work. 
You can learn about it in [the  conditional rendering of react](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)  and in the [the styling in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

Dont hesitate if you got any questions :)